# Count Consecutive Xs If They Total Amount Else Restart

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I essentially have about 300 columns and a few thousand rows that contain Xs. I would like to count the number Xs in a row if they appear consecutively a certain number of times before a blank cell appears. Essentially, the cells will be counted until a blank appears, and if the Xs total 10, the cell with the formula will show True or the count number. I know I can do this with VBA, but I would rather not use VBA. I would also rather not use helper rows since the are thousands of rows that would need to be counted. Is this possible? Thanks!

It would be similar to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1484096/count-cells-in-a-column-between-values-until-specific-value-reached-in-excel), but it would have to iterate until a there are 10 or a False would appear in the cell.

Comment: Hi @Bob the Builder ,, could you please share the expected output since this post has got few answer and both are different !!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample formula, you can scale it up to fit your situation (change reference and search string)

`=IFERROR(SEARCH("xxx", TEXTJOIN("",FALSE,IF(A1:E1="x", "x", 0))), FALSE)`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Enter the *1 or blank* to the first cell, for example I enter the blank to B1 and enter the formula in B2:

```
=IF(A2="","",IF(A1="",1,B1+1))
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

*I would like to suggest 3 possible formula, the better one is in column BH, you may use any of them.*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Enter `1` in cell BG3.
- Formula in cell BG4:

  `=IF(ISBLANK(BF4),"",IF(ISTEXT(BF3),(1+BG3)+0,1))`
- Formula in cell BH3:

  `=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(BF3),NOT(ISNUMBER(BH2))),1,IF(ISBLANK(BF3),"",BH2+1))`
- Formula in cell BI3:

  `=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(BF3)),BI2+1,0)`

**N.B.**

*Adjust cell references as needed.*